# View login status real time

Tags: java, javascript, jmx

I'm on a Java project and I meet the problem with view login user. My client want to see the login user in real time, I have a solution (when login, change status in DB and update on status user table, it's not a real time, update happen when my client have any event...), I know this is bad idea, can somebody give me any solution for this case ?

Thanks.

Comment: are you using any sort of server ? (tomcat/jetty/jboss/whatever?) you could hook into its session management - any new user accessing the system (even if not logged in) would result in the creation of a new web session

Comment: Thanks, I'm Googling...

Comment: How is this connected to JMX?